# Country_of_manufacture Importing Problems

Tags: import, attributes, country, magmi

We have recently started using Magmi to import products...needless to say, this is a great tool. We did, however, notice that country_of_manufacture attribute is not importing. Does anyone know what could cause this and how to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't know Magmi very well, but is this a programming problem?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use code
example: FR for France

Answer (score 1):

Try not use the name of the country, but use the value of the `country_of_manufacture` attribute.

Example: for the United States, use US, not United States.

[Country of Manufacture column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCrqv.jpg)

The following is a complete list of `country_of_manufacture` value in excel format:
[Country of Manufacture List](https://app.box.com/s/1vn184a3mm0yg27ur7934grkfo0tvinm)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question unless you will provide more information. Example CSV would be a good start.

The only things that I'm thinking of why magmi is not importing country_of_manufacture is that you are using full country code value, or your product does not have that attribute at all.

1. Double check that your products has this attribute.
2. Use short country code for country_of_manufacture.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the `country_of_manufacture` attribute uses an own source model.
I have changed the `source_model` in table `eav_attribute` to `eav/entity_attribute_source_table`. Then the options from the attribute management will be used and your import module will have the right option values...